# is there any internal call for requireContext() in android

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-context

I'm using `getContext()` directly without using the `requireContext()`, but I got crash with

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=26316532, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.mypackagename.app.StarterActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment HistoryFragment{6708087} (a45daeaf-7d3c-4091-a1e6-d7ad85ebfb4b) not attached to a context.
   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5571)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5612)
   at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2317)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8625)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

and here I added the usage of the function

```
private fun BaseFragment.updatePermissionsStatus() {
    if (!isAdded) return
    context?.let { fragmentDisposables.add(permissionDomainManager.updatePermissionsStatus(it)) }
}
```

my question is: is there any possibility to have a crash while I'm not using `requierContext()`

By the way I added the part of the Fragment source-code that caused for this crash,

```
/**
 * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
 *
 * @see #requireContext()
 */
@Nullable
public Context getContext() {
    return mHost == null ? null : mHost.getContext();
}

/**
 * Return the {@link Context} this fragment is currently associated with.
 *
 * @throws IllegalStateException if not currently associated with a context.
 * @see #getContext()
 */
@NonNull
public final Context requireContext() {
    Context context = getContext();
    if (context == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + this + " not attached to a context.");
    }
    return context;
}
```

Comment: Examine the stacktrace to learn what code is calling `requireContext()`

Comment: Thank you @laalto for mentioning that, I've added more logs about the crash stacktrace, is not anything related to ```requireContext()```